# onAnimationEnd() Causing app to close

Tags: android

am currently following a book called Sams Teach yourself Android Development in 24 hours.

Things have been going fine till hour 7 where the book teach how to listen for animation end before transisting to another screen (ie splash to menu)

Below are my code. Do help me out. been trying to debug and logcat gives me a 03-06 13:56:57.045: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(746): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception.

QuizSplashActivity.Java

```
  package com.android.triviaquiz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizSplashActivity extends QuizActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        startAnimation();
    }

    private void startAnimation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
        Animation fade1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        logo1.startAnimation(fade1);

        TextView logo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewBottomTitle);
        Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
        logo2.startAnimation(fade2);
        fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){
                startActivity(new Intent(QuizSplashActivity.this,QuizMenuActivity.class));
                QuizSplashActivity.this.finish();

            }


            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }




        });
        Animation spinin = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.custom_anim);
        LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(spinin);
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
            TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
            row.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
        }
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //stop the animation
        TextView logo1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTopTitle);
        logo1.clearAnimation();

        TextView logo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewBottomTitle);
        logo2.clearAnimation();

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout01);
        for (int i = 0; 1< table.getChildCount(); i++){
            TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
            row.clearAnimation();
        }
    }   

}
```

Android Manifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.android.triviaquiz"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/quizicon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".QuizSplashActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity android:name="QuizMenuActivity"></activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>

</manifest>
```

Full LogCat

```
03-06 16:30:35.455: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(775): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
03-06 16:30:35.465: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(775): CheckJNI is ON
03-06 16:30:35.845: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(775): --- registering native functions ---
03-06 16:30:36.405: DEBUG/ddm-heap(775): Got feature list request
03-06 16:30:37.116: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(775): Shutting down VM
03-06 16:30:37.126: DEBUG/dalvikvm(775): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
03-06 16:30:37.126: DEBUG/dalvikvm(775): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down
03-06 16:30:37.136: DEBUG/dalvikvm(775): HeapWorker thread shutting down
03-06 16:30:37.136: DEBUG/dalvikvm(775): HeapWorker thread has shut down
03-06 16:30:37.146: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(775): ERROR: thread attach failed
03-06 16:30:37.146: DEBUG/jdwp(775): JDWP shutting down net...
03-06 16:30:37.166: INFO/dalvikvm(775): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-06 16:30:37.166: DEBUG/dalvikvm(775): VM cleaning up
03-06 16:30:37.215: DEBUG/dalvikvm(775): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 628628 of 5242880 (11%)
03-06 16:30:37.815: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(783): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
03-06 16:30:37.815: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(783): CheckJNI is ON
03-06 16:30:38.146: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(783): --- registering native functions ---
03-06 16:30:38.825: DEBUG/ddm-heap(783): Got feature list request
03-06 16:30:39.575: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.triviaquiz/.QuizSplashActivity }
03-06 16:30:39.655: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(783): Shutting down VM
03-06 16:30:39.665: DEBUG/dalvikvm(783): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
03-06 16:30:39.685: DEBUG/dalvikvm(783): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down
03-06 16:30:39.685: DEBUG/dalvikvm(783): HeapWorker thread shutting down
03-06 16:30:39.705: DEBUG/dalvikvm(783): HeapWorker thread has shut down
03-06 16:30:39.725: DEBUG/jdwp(783): JDWP shutting down net...
03-06 16:30:39.735: INFO/dalvikvm(783): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-06 16:30:39.745: DEBUG/dalvikvm(783): VM cleaning up
03-06 16:30:39.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(783): ERROR: thread attach failed
03-06 16:30:39.865: DEBUG/dalvikvm(783): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 638596 of 5242880 (12%)
03-06 16:30:39.915: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.android.triviaquiz for activity com.android.triviaquiz/.QuizSplashActivity: pid=790 uid=10027 gids={}
03-06 16:30:40.196: DEBUG/ddm-heap(790): Got feature list request
03-06 16:30:41.455: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity com.android.triviaquiz/.QuizSplashActivity: 1799 ms (total 30322 ms)
03-06 16:30:46.295: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.android.triviaquiz/.QuizMenuActivity }
03-06 16:30:46.365: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(790): Shutting down VM
03-06 16:30:46.365: WARN/dalvikvm(790): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
03-06 16:30:46.375: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.android.triviaquiz/com.android.triviaquiz.QuizSplashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3162)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at com.android.triviaquiz.QuizSplashActivity.onPause(QuizSplashActivity.java:77)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3782)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1190)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3149)
03-06 16:30:46.435: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(790):     ... 12 more
03-06 16:30:46.485: INFO/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 790 SIG: 3
03-06 16:30:46.485: INFO/dalvikvm(790): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
03-06 16:30:46.565: INFO/dalvikvm(790): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-06 16:30:46.825: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43db5470 com.android.triviaquiz/.QuizSplashActivity}
03-06 16:30:49.645: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
03-06 16:30:50.340: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43db5470 com.android.triviaquiz/.QuizSplashActivity}
03-06 16:30:56.847: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43dd6cf8 com.android.triviaquiz/.QuizMenuActivity}
03-06 16:31:00.245: DEBUG/dalvikvm(59): GC freed 17596 objects / 838928 bytes in 183ms
03-06 16:31:00.355: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{43db5470 com.android.triviaquiz/.QuizSplashActivity}
```

Comment: Post the _full_ logcat exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this (in your OnPause handler) might be your problem:

```
for (int i = 0; 1< table.getChildCount(); i++){
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++){
```

Notice the second part of the for loop - you're using "1 < table.getChildCount()" instead of "i < table.getChildCount()".

Comment: Oh GOSH! How stupid was I to miss that! A little Typo cost me a good amount of time! Thanks alot pal!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that TableLayout01, TextViewTopTitle and TextViewBottomTitle exist in your layout code?

Comment: Yes they are. The entire app runs fine till onAnimationEnd() where it is supposed to transit to another class in this case QuizMenuActivity where it just crash.